# The expression cannot be written?

Tags: numerical-methods

I am solving exercises, and I found this one. The problem is that my result was:

$2 * 10^{-9}$ , but this answer not appear in the alternatives, what is wrong ?

[image: Exercise]

Comment: your arithmetic is simply incorrect.

Comment: Start by writing it "*in scientific notation*" as $\;\displaystyle \frac{4 \cdot 10^{-3}}{2 \cdot 10^{-4}} \cdot \frac{64 \cdot 10^{-5}}{16 \cdot 10^5}\,$.

Comment: Well 4.64/2.16 = 8 and not 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite everything in terms of scientific notation:

$${4 \cdot 10^{-3} \over 2 \cdot 10^{-4}} \times {6.4 \cdot 10^{-4} \over 1.6 \cdot 10^6}$$

Then divide, coefficient by coefficient and powers of ten by powers of ten. Division means the subtraction of powers, yielding:

$${2 \cdot 10^{-3-(-4)}} \times 4\cdot 10^{-4-6} = 8\cdot 10^{1+(-10)}=8\cdot 10^{-9}$$

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sanity check: forget about the scientific notation, and you have $$\frac{4\cdot 64}{2\cdot 16}=\frac{4\cdot 64}{32}=4\cdot 2=8$$

Hence your answer of $2$ cannot be correct.  If some of the options did not have an $8$, you could eliminate those immediately.  However, since they all begin with $8$, you must now worry about the scientific notation.